# Multiple examples for object properties swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

I am trying to add multiple examples for an Object property.
The Swagger-Ui and Editor version that I am using are

```
'{"swaggerEditor":"3.6.31/g10642b3c-dirty","swaggerUi":{"version":"3.23.0","gitRevision":"g23d7260f","gitDirty":true,"buildTimestamp":"Sat, 29 Jun 2019 19:42:59 GMT","machine":"jenins-swagger-oss"}}'
```

Based on [OpenAPI doc](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/), this version of swagger UI and editor have support for multiple examples but I still see this error:

```
Structural error at components.schemas.MainObject.allOf.3.properties.partitionProperty
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: examples
Jump to line 3016
```

This is how I have added the examples in the property:

```
    MainObject:
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/MainObjectLite'
      - type: object
        description: foobar.
        readOnly: true
        required:
          - fooRequired
        properties:
         fooRequired:
            type: string
            description: system only field used for table data indexing
         partitionProperty:
            type: string
            description: foobar
            examples:
              sampleExample:
                value: 2016-03-04T03:00:00
                summary: sample partition
```

Answer (score 8):

#### OpenAPI 3.0

Multiple `examples` are only supported at the media type level and are not supported inside schemas. Schemas and properties can only have a single `example`, e.g.

```yaml
partitionProperty:
  type: string
  example: '2016-03-04T03:00:00'
```

In other words, this won't work:

```yaml
MainObject:
  type: object
  properties:
    ..
  examples:  # <--- Won't work
    minimal:
      summary: Minimal example
      value:
        foo: bar
    full:
      summary: Example with all properties
      value:
        foo: bar
        baz: xyzzy
```

If you want multiple `examples`, you need to use request examples or response examples instead:

```yaml
requestBody:
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/MainObject'
      examples:
        minimal:
          summary: Minimal example
          value:
            foo: bar
        full:
          summary: Example with all properties
          value:
            foo: bar
            baz: xyzzy
```

#### OpenAPI 3.1

OAS 3.1 uses a newer version of JSON Schema which supports multiple `examples` in schemas and properties. Unlike media type `examples` which is a map of named Example Objects, schema-level and property-level `examples` is a plain list of example values.

```yaml
MyObject:
  type: object
  properties:
    prop1:
      type: string
      # Property-level examples
      examples:
        - foo
        - bar
    prop2:
      type: integer

  # Object-level examples
  examples:
    - prop1: hello
      prop2: 5
    - prop1: world
      prop2: 0
```

Comment: https://www.openapis.org/blog/2021/02/16/migrating-from-openapi-3-0-to-3-1-0
Here is an example

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck on OpenAPI v3.0.x and need (strongly desire) multiple examples,
here is a hackish way to provide them within the schemas section (Note single quotes outside and double quotes inside):

```
common_phone:
  type: string
  maxLength: 14
  minLength: 1
  example: "'(614) 555-1212' or '614.555.1212' or '614-555-1212' or '6145551212'"
```